# slurm submission script for MPI + OpenMP + hyperthreading question

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, slurm, hpc

I wrote a C++ code which uses MPI and OpenMP inside each MPI process.

I have just got access to a cluster which is composed of AMD compute nodes, each such compute node being a `AMD Epyc 7502`.

I went into an interactive session with `salloc` and got 1 such node for myself.
I then ran some commands in the terminal to understand the configuration of 1 compute node.

I gather that each node has 32 physical cores and 64 logical cores.
It means that each physical core can launch 2 threads.

Each node has 4 NUMA regions, output of `lscpu | grep -i numa` being as below:

```
NUMA node(s):          4
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7,32-39
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     8-15,40-47
NUMA node2 CPU(s):     16-23,48-55
NUMA node3 CPU(s):     24-31,56-63
```

The output of `$ lscpu` is as below:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                64
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-63
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    32
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          4
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            23
Model:                 49
Model name:            AMD EPYC 7502P 32-Core Processor
Stepping:              0
CPU MHz:               1500.000
CPU max MHz:           2500.0000
CPU min MHz:           1500.0000
BogoMIPS:              5000.17
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              512K
L3 cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7,32-39
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     8-15,40-47
NUMA node2 CPU(s):     16-23,48-55
NUMA node3 CPU(s):     24-31,56-63
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_l2 cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate sme ssbd rsb_ctxsw ibrs ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif umip overflow_recov succor smca
```

I want to ask you why a `SLURM` submission script as below fails with the error:

```
sbatch: error: CPU count per node can not be satisfied
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available
```

The submission script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=AMD_MPI_OMP
#SBATCH --time=00:35:00
#SBATCH -p scarf
#SBATCH -C amd
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4
#SBATCH --hint=multithread
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16

module load AMDmodules
module load GCC/12.2.0

# Propagate the cpus-per-task setting from script to srun commands
#    By default, Slurm does not propagate this setting from the sbatch
#    options to srun commands in the job script. If this is not done,
#    process/thread pinning may be incorrect leading to poor performance
export SRUN_CPUS_PER_TASK=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK

# Set the number of threads to 16 and specify placement
#   There are 16 OpenMP threads per MPI process
#   We want two threads per 1 physical core

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=16
export OMP_PLACES=threads
export OMP_PROC_BIND=true

mpirun -srun ./solver_parallelized_afterTamio1_AMD
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should check how SLURM have its nodes configured. Despite the physical CPU, the SLURM node can be configured as the administrator desires. If he decides that each node only have 1 CPU to be managed under SLURM, then SLURM will tell you that the request cannot be fulfilled. Maybe Hyperthreading is not enabled/considered and then you should ask for 2 tasks per node and 4 nodes. Or just ask for 8 tasks and let SLURM distribute them in as many nodes as needed.